# Performance metrics for outlier/anomaly detection

Tags: anomaly-detection, metric

I am currently seeking for metrics i can use to evaluate a model for outlier/anomaly detection without ground truth. The only thing i came up with for now is to use the scores/probas returned by my model and interpret it.

I assume that if the distribution is very skewed, my model is doing good at separating outliers and inliers, is it a correct way to evaluate ?  I tried to look up for classic unsupervised metric that use predictions rather than the scores but this does not look trivial to me. Any ideas on this problem ?

Comment: You are right that this is not trivial. If you do not know what is an "outlier" in your case, how can you expect a model to know? Asymmetric distributions tell many stories, outliers is just one possible case.

Comment: Performance metrics need to be guided by your particular application. It should reflect what "better" means for your particular usecase and scenario. So what is desirable / not desirable in your case?